# PHP restrict access, download after submit only

Tags: php, security, download

I want to be able to restrict access of a download only when someone has used the Sign Up form (after submit). The HTML/PHP cannot be accessible through copy/paste or posted link.

Here's what I have so far:
**Server:** The "Downloads" folder on the server has an .htaccess file with

```
<Files download.pdf>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

**Website:** On the form, after submit there's a PHP contact-form-handler that sends the sign-up info to an email address and a redirect to the "Thank You - Here's Your Download html page." I have added on this html page

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://www.pathtofilehere/signupform.php">
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.pathtofilehere/signupform.php"> Get Your Download Now!</a>
```

The "Thank You - Here's Your Download" page then prompts the automatic download PHP.

```
<?php
$filename = "download.pdf";
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))ini_set('zli b.output_compression', 'Off');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();
?>
```

I am on a tester server so I can't move the "Downloads" out of the root. I will move it out of the root once I get this set up. And another problem...the owner of the website doesn't have database set up. So a login wouldn't work at this point. In the meantime...

What I want to happen: The download only be available after "Submit" of the form. Right now, I can access the download through the html page. or the PHP page. I've tried [Gateway PHP --> Protected File PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254999/775781%20%22Gateway%20PHP--%3EProtected%20Page%20PHP) on the forum and couldn't get it to work. Can I set some sort of parameter, session, to pass through to make this only visible/accessible to the "Signed-Up" persons?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You'd be far safer keeping that pdf OUTSIDE of your document root. Since you're providing access to it via script only, moving it out of the doc root adds another layer of security, and will KEEP it secure in case that order/deny gets changed in the future.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this on a tester server so I can't move the "Downloads" out of the root. I will move it out of the root once I get this set up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way (without a login of any kind) would be to add a session variable that gets set when the visitor presses submit and checked in the download page for existence.

Just add something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['submitted'] = 'somevalue';
```

at the top of the page that handles the submit and:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['submitted']))
{
  // do whatever you want to do
  die();    // stop further execution
}

$filename = "download.pdf";
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))ini_set('zli b.output_compression', 'Off');
header("Pragma: public");
....
```

at the top of the download script you posted.

However, as you are talking about signing up, you can also add functionality that allows users to login at a later time to get the file (if the signup is related to a user account anyway). Then you would have your users login and check for a logged in user at the top of the download page.

Comment: That's another problem...the owner of the website doesn't have database set up. So a login wouldn't work at this point. I know, they really do need a database. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrea The first solution does not need a database. I have added a simple code example.

Comment: @Andrea No, you need the two different pages (requests from the visitors browser...), the Thank You page to handle the submission and set the variable, and the download page to test for it. Note that you need to test with a different browser or destroy the session in order to see that you really cannot access it without submitting first.

Comment: 'code'$_SESSION['submitted'] = 'somevalue'; Does something other than 'somevalue' go here or is this ok? Will test with another browser. Thanks, Jeroen.

Comment: @Andrea In my example I am not even checking for the value, I am just check if it is set, so it does not matter what you use there.

Comment: I can't access the download via the download script PHP page in another browser. It's just a blank page. Yay!

Comment: @Andrea You should probably redirect to another page where I wrote `// do whatever you want to do` or give a nice error message.

Comment: Yep I already did. {echo 'You must <a href="http://www.signuppagehere.html">Sign Up</a> to access this file';

Answer (score 1):

the global `$_POST[]` contains particular form values which are submitted through the post method only.

If you wrap your script around with some checks regarding this variable, you might get to a solution.

To be on the safe side, you could render some kind of hash will be submitted also through the form ad compare them with the expected.