# Access php-file only through page

Tags: php

I am serving pictures and videos through a php-file (let's call it serveMedia.php) to my index.php.
I use mod_rewrite, php-sessions and a token included in the URL to call those media files from the index.php, e.g. `src="media=SOMEFILENAME&type=jpeg&token=2134573946284615492345"`
The media-files themselves lie in a folder with restricted acces by .htaccess (`deny from all`)

Now my question: is there any possibility to make this URL only accessible through my index.php?
What I try to achieve is that users can see the content only when it is delivered through my page and not when they visit it's URL.

Maybe there are some advanced .htaccess or php-options I don't know?
I'm on a hosted space so these two are probably my only options.

This is what I'm working with at the moment:

**index.php**

```
ob_start();

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] !== session_id()){
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}
else {
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
};
```

**serveMedia.php:**

```
if(isset($_GET['token']) 
    && $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token'] 
    && $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] == session_id()){

        //streamthisfile!

else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "no file";
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt a variable (like the current date) and placed that in the "gate" link. When you arrive at the new page, a script decrypts the variable and if it doesn't match or isn't even there, the script redirects to another page.

Something like:

```
     <a href="restricted.php?pass=eERadWRWE3ad=">Go!</a>
```

There are several libraries out there that can do all the encryption/decryption for you.

Other wise you have to rely over session i.e your Previous method or You can use HTTP_Refferer(not reliable)

Here :
[Restricting access to page unless coming from a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254929/restricting-access-to-page-unless-coming-from-a-specific-page)

Comment: I'm generating the token by using `$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));`. I tried `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))` but this is not safe and e.g. iPhone won't play video anymore.

Comment: y you are using http_referrer,
generate the value on page, store the same value in database, the page on which you are serving videos just retrieve the pass value using $_GET['pass'] and confirm it with database value if it matches go ahead otherwise redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the HTTP header `referer` is set to the source page for an image request, so you could use that to determine if you serve the resource or not.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'my/index.php') {
  //serve page
}
```

Comment: This is browser-specific and not always set, right? And the name of the page I'm referring from isn't static...